# Ignoring Dynamic Text Setting In iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, text, dynamic, react-native

I have done a bit of googling around and I am looking for a simple solution to completely ignore the users dynamic text settings in iOS and display them use what I have set in my app itself.  My app is a react-native iOS/Android app.

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Disallow font-scaling

The [`Text`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html) Component supports the prop `allowFontScaling`.

> Specifies should fonts scale to respect Text Size accessibility
>   setting on iOS.

```
<Text allowFontScaling={false}>Hello World!</Text>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I am not sure how I missed that in the docs

Comment: @BenDellarocco just hit the accept button, to help others with the same question